# Enable Datalayers for Hubspot with GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, data-layers, hubspot-cms

Is there any way to enable Data layers in a website (built-in Hubspot) with GTM?
Is there any article or tool?

Answer (score 0):

If you already deployed GTM on the site, then you have it. GTM deploys dataLayer automatically. You can check it in the dev console.

If you need to push certain things into it, Hubspot lists its globally accessible variables to be used [here](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/cms/hubl/variables#http-request-variables) but you can as well just use them without dataLayer since GTM has all the JS presence needed to grab those variables from the global scope.

And [here](https://community.hubspot.com/t5/APIs-Integrations/Google-Tag-Manager-Push-Form-Data-to-dataLayer/m-p/526052) is an example of pushing the data from hubspot to the dataLayer.